# Next page button takes me to the same page

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-wordpress-pages

I'm trying to have a "previous page" and "next page" links for a particular page (not the main/home page).

When I click on the "next page" link, the page looks the same but the URL says "paged=2".

This code is in the `index.php` file and works for the main/home page (for  next/previous links). But it doesn't work with the page I'm working on, which has a page-template (`page-books.php`).

In the `page-books.php` I have the same piece of code:

```
<div class="nav-home-next">

    <p><?php previous_posts_link('<'); ?>
    <?php next_posts_link('>'); ?></p>

</div>
```

The full template I'm using that someone else has made (with a few modifications) is here:
http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/63eba611a3ffbc1bb564cfd1a3b02f1971dc7a00

In another question from someone else, there was this answer: "You're using `paged` in the URL, but your code is looking for `$_GET['page']`

I don't have `$_GET['page']` or `paged` in my code. So I think paged is the default.

I'm not sure as to what to do (I'm still new to coding). How do I get it to work like the main/home page?

Something that could be effecting its output is this code in the functions.php:

```
function excludeCat($query) {
if ( $query->is_home ) {
$query->set('cat', '-26');
}
return $query;
}
add_filter('pre_get_posts', 'excludeCat');
```

It removes and posts in the 'books' category from the main page. I don't think it would but I thought it could be useful to know.

Comment: Have you tried using `previous_posts_link('&#60;')` and `next_posts_link('&#62;')` instead?

Comment: This is not enough, you need to post the code for the `previous_posts_link()` function and the `next_posts_link()` function

Comment: @TonyMorello I think I'm just using the default code for them. I don't have anything specified in `functions.php`.
https://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/next_posts_link

Comment: @Tigger Changing it to '&#60;' didn't work either.